# saving the pdf using phpexcel terminate the rest of the script

Tags: php, phpexcel, dompdf

the echo statement is not running and the below script is also not running

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                header("Pragma: public");
                header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                header("Cache-Control: private", false);
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="rename.pdf"'); //tell browser what's the file name
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
                $objWriter->setSheetIndex($i);

                $objWriter->save('php://output');
               echo "this is not diplaying"; //code get terminated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't echo anything when you're sending data to `php://output` with file headers.... echo sends its data to `php://output`..... all you're doing is writing `"this is not diplaying"` at the bottom of the file that you're sending.... and the likelihood is that it will also corrupt that file

Comment: Yes..... don't ever echo anything else when you're outputting a file to the browser..... this isn't PHPExcel specific, it applies to any file generated or written to php://output by PHP.... you can only send one content type to a browser in response to one request